# Difference between "ts" warning and "eslint@typescript-eslint/*" in vscode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm getting warnings from both typescript and eslint in my editor e.g.

```
const foo = 'bar'

'foo' is declared but its value is never read ts(6133)
'foo' is assigned a value but never used.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
```

I'm not sure which one I need to suppress. For reference, here is my `.eslintrc`:

```
{
  "extends": "react-app"
}
```

and my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

What settings in vscode do I need to disable/enable to fix these redundant warnings?

Comment: Do you see the same `ts` error on the command line if you compile your code using `tsc`?